# How to create only internal loadbalancer with ingress without external one by using Helm Chart installation?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, internal-load-balancer

I am looking for a following solution. How to create only internal loadbalancer with ingress without external one by using Helm Chart installation? Normally ingress installation install's external loadbalancer which is later registered to Domain and all is fine. In my case we will have an internal server that will require Internal Loadbalancer. I am using ingress-nginx just because CloudBees (target service) is using that technology, however I didn't managed it. I have created manually an internal loadbalancer and then an ingress, but it's not an enterprise solution. Ideally I have to install ingress-nginx that way, that only ingress loadbalancer will be installed. Please help me find a way how to do it.

Maybe you made such a thing in a past and you could help me a bit :)

Here is how I proceed for now.

for cloudbees [installation](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/gke-install-guide/gke-pre-install-requirements) preparation I use [ingress-nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/) installation.

```
INGRESS_EXAMPLE_NS=cloudbees-core
kubectl create ns $INGRESS_EXAMPLE_NS
kubens $INGRESS_EXAMPLE_NS

helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update

#install ingress
helm upgrade -i ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

I have listed all values that are possible with

```
 helm show values ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx > values-nginx.yaml
```

I will give a shot for:

```
  internal:
     enabled: false
     annotations: {}
```

Thanks a lot for all who participate in solution findings.

Comment: you can make your own helm chart with the ingress you need and then call the ingress-nginx as a dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
annotations:
  ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "tls-service-example-net-ip"
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
  kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: sip-service-ingress-eu-west3
  kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
```

Creating it via Helm Chart without ingress-nginx and rellaying on GKE LB is the solution. By Service creation additional annotation was also required:

```
cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
```

If you have that issue it might help you.